# Are my steps to generate random values based on a given dataset correct?

Tags: probability-distributions, random

I have a dataset of 100 cases. Each case has a class {I,II,III,IV,V} and a value A and V, each class appears exactly 20 times in the dataset:

```
Class   A   V
5       2   3
1       3   5
3       2   3
2       3   5
3       2   3
1       2   4
1       2   4
1       4   4
2       3   3
2       3   4
```

I want to generate another 100 cases based on this set. Am i correct in assuming that I should

1. find the distribution of A and the distribution of V per class?
2. calculate the joint distribution of A & V per class
3. get random numbers based on this joint distribution

I am confused about whether i should assume any relation between A and V or that any relation should come from the joint distribution (and assume their independent)?

Thank you